# fatal error: 'FlutterAppDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I cannot run Flutter for iOS simulator, I use iPhone XS Simulator. There is nothing issue when I run with Android Emulator.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/user/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.8+1/ios/Classes/FLTConnectivityPlugin.h:5:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/app/ios/Pods/../Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:54:10: fatal error: 'FlutterAppDelegate.h' file not found
    #include "FlutterAppDelegate.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/user/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.8+1/ios/Classes/FLTConnectivityPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/user/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.8+1/ios/Classes/FLTConnectivityPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Flutter'
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xs.
```

This is flutter doctor detail.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.14.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale en-ID)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Anyone can help me? thank you...

Comment: Any solution, having the same issue.